# SQL Query Time Complexity - Join vs Sub Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, subquery

My question is regarding dilemma when using `join` and `sub-query` methods give the same results,

Which one is better and faster? *(**purely** in terms of **time complexity**)*

Does `join` take `O(M+N)` time complexity? and does `sub-query`take `O(M*N)`?

Am I wrong to think this way? If yes, pls correct me.

Here, (M, N) are number of rows in both tables combining which the results are obtained.

I am looking for answers based on SQL standard not just MySQL.

P.S - I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549/5213405) question and all the answers to it. It is not essentially concerned about Time Complexity part.

Comment: Query planning modules in MySQL (and other RDMSs) are complex enough that the only conceivable answer to this question is "it depends." Some queries can be transformed, by the planner, from a subquery form to a join form. Others can't. Indexes, and table cardinality, both go into the query planners' decision making.

Comment: Any hints on O(M+N) and O(M*N) part? @O.Jones

Comment: generally the join perform better  .. but as suggest by O.Jones  .. "depends "

Comment: In most modern databases, the query optimizer is smart enough to create the best execution plan in either case. Sometimes, when possible, a sub query will be executed the same as a join.

Comment: Any hints on O(M+N) and O(M*N) part? (time complexity w.r.t number of rows). I have read in a post that hashing techniques could be used by compiler in joins which is not the case in sub queries. @scaisEdge

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Does join take O(M+N) time complexity? and does sub-querytake O(M*N)?
>   Am I wrong to think this way?

Yes, with respect, you are wrong to think this way.  SQL is *declarative.* You use it to state the result you want, and the server figures out the best way to deliver that result -- to satisfy your query -- based on available indexes and data structures.

Thousands of years -- really! -- of developer effort have gone into figuring out all sorts of algorithms, optimizations, and hacks to reduce the complexity of the processes the servers use to satisfy queries.

As the thousands of years of experience accumulate the performance distinction between correlated subqueries and join queries gets less important.

Your thinking is wrong for a specific reason: you are thinking *procedurally,* not *declaratively.* When you assert that a particular type of query can be satisfied in, for example, `O(m*n)` time, you are making assumptions about procedures used to satisfy it. Generations of developers have been dedicated to making your assumptions wrong.

Certainly it's possible to create tables, indexes, and queries with pathological performance characteristics. It happens all the time. But somebody fixes an index and the problem is solved.

Comment: Best answer I could ever expect.!! Thanks @O Jones for stating the specific reasons. Made the concept clear now.

Comment: This is of course 100% correct ... in theory. In practice there are some declarative patterns that are parsed into AST that aren't easily transformed by query optimizers into performant execution. _Correlated subqueries_  are one such example. Some RDBMS don't even support the syntax for that exact reason (e.g. Snowflake as at June 2020)

Answer (score -1):

As far as my understanding The performance should be the same. It is much more important to have the correct indexes and clustering applied on your tables.

Comment: Any hints on O(M+N) and O(M*N) part? (time complexity w.r.t number of rows). I have read in a post that hashing techniques could be used by compiler in joins which is not the case in sub queries.